# Woocommerce - Change price display in cart and checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm creating a webshop with WooCommerce in WordPress, using swedish krona (SEK) as currency. It should be displayed after the price, i.e. "2999 kr", and not "kr2999", but I can't get it to work on the cart and the checkout page, and not cart in the header.

I've found this filter for the cart total price, which is working but only on the total price in checkout:

functions.php

```
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_totals_order_total_html', 'total_price');

function total_price() {
    $price_html = substr(WC()->cart->get_total(),33);
    $replace_price = substr_replace($price_html, ' kr', 49);
    $value = '<strong>' . $replace_price . '</strong> ';
    return $value;
}
```

How do I do this for every price display in cart and checkout and cart in header? It should be similar to the code above?

[image: Header cart price display]

Comment: this might help: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83367/how-to-edit-the-get-price-html-on-woocommerce

Comment: This is related to adding a price suffix instead: http://www.codemyownroad.com/add-currency-code-suffix-prices-woocommerce/